# move_group Python interface collision and visual mesh

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the Python move_group interface for MoveIt.

`planning_scene_interface.py` specifies a function `add_mesh` to add a model to the scene, limited to only 1 mesh file.
Is it possible to add a model with both a collision and visual mesh to the planning scene?
I mean similar to how we specify collision and visual meshes for links in xacro files.

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346908/move_group-python-interface-collision-and-visual-mesh/) by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

That function is really just for publishing a "collision object".

It's not meant for adding arbitrary geometry to the scene.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
If you could describe what you are looking to do exactly, perhaps an alternative could be found.

**Comment by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on 2020-03-17**:
My goal is to visualize the robot task in realtime at the same time with the physical robot, including objects that are being moved

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
If it's just for visualisation, you could consider publishing Markers. [rviz_visual_tools](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/rviz_visual_tools) could help you with that.

If those objects should be taken into account by the motion planner, you really should be publishing collision objects.

You could of course combine this.